# Parsing input string with antlr grammar

Tags: antlr, antlr4

I have a following problem with the grammar:

The input string i'm going to parse is as follows:

```
ruledef COMPLEX1 
    ftp command args = abc
    ftp command args = ftp
    ftp command args = cde
exit
```

The grammar i use:

```
grammar main;

/*Lexical*/
NUM : [0-9]+;
STRING : [0-9a-zA-Z]+;
WS : [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip; // Whitespace definition: skip spaces, tabs and newlines

ruledefrule: 'ruledef' STRING (ruledef_ftpcommandargsrule )* 'exit';
ruledef_ftpcommandargsrule: 'ftp' 'command' 'args' '=' STRING ;
```

When i run it through antlr i receive an error:

```
line 3:23 missing STRING at 'ftp'
```

What is more any of the words used in the input for example 'command' or 'args' causes the same problem.

```
ftp command args = ftp
ftp command args = args
ftp command args = command
```

Does anybody know how to deal with that kind of problems?

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that string literals in your grammar such as `'ruledef'` and `'exit'` implicitly have their own token types and are matched before everything else, including before `STRING`. Therefore, `STRING` does not contain `'ruledef'`, `'exit'`, `'ftp'`, `'command'`, and `'args'` in its set of possible values. It is as if you have implicitly written the following grammar:

```
grammar main;

/* Lexical */
RULEDEF : 'ruledef' ;
EXIT : 'exit' ;
FTP : 'ftp' ;
COMMAND : 'command' ;
ARGS : 'args' ;
NUM : [0-9]+ ;
STRING : [0-9a-zA-Z]+ ;
WS : [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip ; // Whitespace definition: skip spaces, tabs and newlines

ruledefrule : RULEDEF STRING ruledef_ftpcommandargsrule* EXIT ;
ruledef_ftpcommandargsrule : FTP COMMAND ARGS '=' STRING ;
```

The grammar above doesn't support the inputs you mentioned because `'ruledef'`, `'exit'`, `'ftp'`, `'command'`, and `'args'` are all captured by tokens other than `STRING` so they do not match it in `ruledef_ftpcommandargsrule`. The way to solve this is to make another rule, let's call it `string`, which can be `STRING`, `'ruledef'`, `'exit'`, `'ftp'`, `'command'`, or `'args'`. And then use that rule in place of `STRING` where ever the behavior is desired:

```
grammar main;

/* Lexical */
NUM : [0-9]+ ;
STRING : [0-9a-zA-Z]+ ;
WS : [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip ; // Whitespace definition: skip spaces, tabs and newlines

ruledefrule : 'ruledef' string ruledef_ftpcommandargsrule* 'exit' ;
ruledef_ftpcommandargsrule : 'ftp' 'command' 'args' '=' string ;
string : STRING | 'ruledef' | 'exit' | 'ftp' | 'command' | 'args' ;
```

Let me know if you'd like me to clarify anything.

Answer (score -2):

Change the order of your lexical rules `NUM`and `STRING`.

Their precedence is made by their order, so first come first serve.

Have fun with ANTLR, its a nice tool.

Comment: Hi. Thanks. This is not solution for the problem. Changing the sequence doesn't solve the problem. The snipped presented here is just a little portion of the bigger grammar.